# Static mockup of a website

Tags: css, html5

I'm diving into front-end stuff for the first time. I thought a good way to get started was to try to do a mockup of a website. I took the top part of [Microsoft's home page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/). Here's a [link to the codepen](https://codepen.io/logicOnAbstractions/pen/rNxrJRE). Full code at the end of the question as well.

- Not a full/exact replica. Would need much more time for me.
- Used HTML5 boilerplate. No need to review/comment the boilerplate. *My CSS for review is from the beginning of the CSS code up to the comment*. Comments on the relevance or not of using boilerplate are welcomed.

I'm mostly interested in knowing:

- if there are common naming conventions in UI that I'm not respecting
- if the choice of structure (how to use `<div> <a>  <img>` to produce the navbar, hero, etc.) is consistent with best practices
- if the use of css selectors is appropriate, especially if I this were at larger scale
- any other newbie mistake that jumps to the eyes of an experience front-end dev
- I tried to make it responsive. I know media queries may be the way to go for that, but I tried to achieve it with just flex/grid. Any comments on that aspect very welcomed.

Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <meta property="og:title" content="">
  <meta property="og:type" content="">
  <meta property="og:url" content="">
  <meta property="og:image" content="">

  <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">
  <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <!--font awesome link for quick icons etc. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#fafafa">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <!--allowing different html pages to define reusable components & reuse them easily-->
<!--  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("html/test.html");
    });
    </script>-->
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="mainnav">
      <div class="mainnav_left">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/wwLhz98/logo.png" alt="Microsoft">
        <a href="#">Microsoft 365</a>
        <a href="#">Office</a>
        <a href="#">Windows</a>
        <a href="#">Surface</a>
        <a href="#">Xbox</a>
        <a href="#">Deals</a>
        <a href="#">Support</a>
      </div>
      <div class="mainnav_right">
        <a href="#"> <i class="fas fa-search fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="hero">
      <div class="hero_topbanner"><a href="#" id="hero_link">Our covid 19 response </a></div>
      <div class="hero_main">
        <h1>Spend $$$, save $$$</h1>
        <p>Find stuff you like, buy it, and somehow justify your purchases by thinking your could always have paid more for the stuff somehow!</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Help me spend!<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="icon_banner">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/gZttF3G/ic-office.png" alt="MS office">Paid google docs</a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/fq7ZRg7/ezgif-com-webp-to-png.png" alt="Surface">Android alternatives</a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/CQRGjkS/ic-xbox.png" alt="ic-xbox" border="0">Playstation-like machine</a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/MS2pFSY/ic-windows.png" alt="Windows">Avoid a linux install</a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/yVfxppL/ic-pc.png" alt="PC">Avoid MacOs</a>
    </div>
  </div><!--wrapper-->
</body>

</html>

And the CSS:

:root{
  --link_color_dark:#000;
  --link_color_light:#eee;
  --link_color_mid:#444;
}

a, a:visited {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color:var(--link_color_mid);
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.btn:hover{
  opacity: 0.9;
}
i {
  margin: 1em 0.5em;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}
.mainnav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;
  margin: 2em 1em;
}
.mainnav_right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;

}
.mainnav_left a, .mainnav_right a {
  margin: 0em 0.5em;
  color: var(--link_color_mid);
}
.hero_topbanner {
  background-color: #082887;
  color: #aaa;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
.hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/gymg4Nw/RE4ACjC.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 600px;
}
.hero_main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: start;
  margin: 2em 4em;
  max-width: 400px;
  color: var(--link_color_mid);
}

.hero_main * {
  margin: 0.5em 0em;
}

.hero_topbanner a, .hero_topbanner a:visited {
  color: var(--link_color_light);
}
.hero_main a, .hero_main a:visited {
  background-color: #222;
  color: var(--link_color_light);
}
.btn  {
  margin: 1em 0em;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14em;
}
.btn:hover i {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.icon_banner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.icon_banner a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  width: 1fr;
  margin: 2em 2em;
}

/*
#########################################
#########################################
#########################################

########### END OF CODE REVIEW ##########

#########################################
#########################################
#########################################
*/

/*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */

/* Document
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Correct the line height in all browsers.
 * 2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
 */

html {
  line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/* Sections
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the margin in all browsers.
 */

body {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
}

/**
 * Render the `main` element consistently in IE.
 */

main {
  display: block;
}

/**
 * Correct the font size and margin on `h1` elements within `section` and
 * `article` contexts in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
 */

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in Firefox.
 * 2. Show the overflow in Edge and IE.
 */

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box; /* 1 */
  height: 0; /* 1 */
  overflow: visible; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */

pre {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the gray background on active links in IE 10.
 */

a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove the bottom border in Chrome 57-
 * 2. Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera, and Safari.
 */

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none; /* 1 */
  text-decoration: underline; /* 2 */
  text-decoration: underline dotted; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
 */

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */

code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct font size in all browsers.
 */

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in
 * all browsers.
 */

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the border on images inside links in IE 10.
 */

img {
  border-style: none;
  max-width: 100%;        /*prevent images from overflowing their div*/

}

/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
 * 2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
 */

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit; /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
  line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
  margin: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Show the overflow in IE.
 * 1. Show the overflow in Edge.
 */

button,
input { /* 1 */
  overflow: visible;
}

/**
 * Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge, Firefox, and IE.
 * 1. Remove the inheritance of text transform in Firefox.
 */

button,
select { /* 1 */
  text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 */

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

/**
 * Remove the inner border and padding in Firefox.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Restore the focus styles unset by the previous rule.
 */

button:-moz-focusring,
[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
}

/**
 * Correct the padding in Firefox.
 */

fieldset {
  padding: 0.35em 0.75em 0.625em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the text wrapping in Edge and IE.
 * 2. Correct the color inheritance from `fieldset` elements in IE.
 * 3. Remove the padding so developers are not caught out when they zero out
 *    `fieldset` elements in all browsers.
 */

legend {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  color: inherit; /* 2 */
  display: table; /* 1 */
  max-width: 100%; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 3 */
  white-space: normal; /* 1 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/**
 * Remove the default vertical scrollbar in IE 10+.
 */

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in IE 10.
 * 2. Remove the padding in IE 10.
 */

[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Chrome.
 */

[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
 * 2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
 */

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
 */

[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 * 2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
 */

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
  font: inherit; /* 2 */
}

/* Interactive
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Add the correct display in Edge, IE 10+, and Firefox.
 */

details {
  display: block;
}

/*
 * Add the correct display in all browsers.
 */

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/* Misc
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10+.
 */

template {
  display: none;
}

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10.
 */

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

/*my main.css*/
/*! HTML5 Boilerplate v8.0.0 | MIT License | https://html5boilerplate.com/ */

/* main.css 2.1.0 | MIT License | https://github.com/h5bp/main.css#readme */
/*
 * What follows is the result of much research on cross-browser styling.
 * Credit left inline and big thanks to Nicolas Gallagher, Jonathan Neal,
 * Kroc Camen, and the H5BP dev community and team.
 */

/* ==========================================================================
   Base styles: opinionated defaults
   ========================================================================== */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

/*
 * Remove text-shadow in selection highlight:
 * https://twitter.com/miketaylr/status/12228805301
 *
 * Vendor-prefixed and regular ::selection selectors cannot be combined:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/16982510/7133471
 *
 * Customize the background color to match your design.
 */

::-moz-selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}

/*
 * A better looking default horizontal rule
 */

hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*
 * Remove the gap between audio, canvas, iframes,
 * images, videos and the bottom of their containers:
 * https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/440
 */

audio,
canvas,
iframe,
img,
svg,
video {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/*
 * Remove default fieldset styles.
 */

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*
 * Allow only vertical resizing of textareas.
 */

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== */

/* ==========================================================================
   Helper classes
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Hide visually and from screen readers
 */

.hidden,
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}

/*
 * Hide only visually, but have it available for screen readers:
 * https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility
 *
 * 1. For long content, line feeds are not interpreted as spaces and small width
 *    causes content to wrap 1 word per line:
 *    https://medium.com/@jessebeach/beware-smushed-off-screen-accessible-text-5952a4c2cbfe
 */

.sr-only {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
  /* 1 */
}

/*
 * Extends the .sr-only class to allow the element
 * to be focusable when navigated to via the keyboard:
 * https://www.drupal.org/node/897638
 */

.sr-only.focusable:active,
.sr-only.focusable:focus {
  clip: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: static;
  white-space: inherit;
  width: auto;
}

/*
 * Hide visually and from screen readers, but maintain layout
 */

.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix::before,
.clearfix::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   EXAMPLE Media Queries for Responsive Design.
   These examples override the primary ('mobile first') styles.
   Modify as content requires.
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
  /* Style adjustments for viewports that meet the condition */
}

@media print,
  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
  (min-resolution: 1.25dppx),
  (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
  /* Style adjustments for high resolution devices */
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Print styles.
   Inlined to avoid the additional HTTP request:
   https://www.phpied.com/delay-loading-your-print-css/
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    background: #fff !important;
    color: #000 !important;
    /* Black prints faster */
    box-shadow: none !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
  }

  a,
  a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

  a[href]::after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  }

  abbr[title]::after {
    content: " (" attr(title) ")";
  }

  /*
   * Don't show links that are fragment identifiers,
   * or use the `javascript:` pseudo protocol
   */
  a[href^="#"]::after,
  a[href^="javascript:"]::after {
    content: "";
  }

  pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap !important;
  }

  pre,
  blockquote {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }

  /*
   * Printing Tables:
   * https://web.archive.org/web/20180815150934/http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Printing_Tables
   */
  thead {
    display: table-header-group;
  }

  tr,
  img {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }

  p,
  h2,
  h3 {
    orphans: 3;
    widows: 3;
  }

  h2,
  h3 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
}
```